# images are registered in Wordpress media library but still don't display

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on creating a copy of a wordpress site on a separate domain hosted on the same server as the original. I created the new database with the correct domain and everything is working properly except the images are showing up as grey boxes in the library. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Broken Wordpress Intallation]

The images that are properly displaying were uploaded after or added in with a "media from ftp" plugin which was unable to find any other images.

I've checked the files on the server and they still contain the images. Uploading each image again would be very time consuming so I was wondering if there is any solution that will fix the registered images rather than having to do that.

EDIT: Also wanted to add that I set the permissions on the uploads folder and all subfolders/files to 777 and it still isn't working. The URL's on the image details page are correct and when I visit it in my browser the image shows up, but not in wordpress.

Here's the image details page: 
[image: image details page]

And what that url shows in the browser:
[image: image url]

Comment: When you checked that the files where on the server did you notice if they were available in different sizes? It may be that you have to regenerate your thumbnails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I still don't know what the issue is, I found a workaround:

If you delete the images in the Media library the files will remain on the server and you can use any of the numerous "upload images via ftp" plugins to add them back into your library. I used "Media from ftp" and it got the job done. Hope this helps anyone who has this problem in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Permission issue?? try to assign 777 to the whole ./wp-content/uploads if it will fix your issue, **don't forget to assign the correct permissions**

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I just went in and did it again and still no dice.

Comment: If this is not helping, then the issue is in internal links I found for you a really nice "tutorial" how to change them all :) here -> http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/01/30/13-useful-wordpress-sql-queries-you-wish-you-knew-earlier/

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving your content to a new domain you'll need to update the database entries for the image URLs, since the URLs will now be different. If you have access to the DB (via PHPMyAdmin for example) you can do this with a find and replace. Check [this article](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/updating-wordpress-mysql-database-after-moving-to-a-new-url/) for more details.

Comment: I used http://pixelentity.com/wordpress-search-replace-domain/ which was mentioned in the wordpress codex on moving wordpress sites. Everything else is working it's just the images that aren't showing up properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on a local server where I had got images from the web. All the images downloaded but one wasn't showing on the web page or in the media library.
The image that was showing a grey box in the media library had a **%2B** hex code in the URL. After this was removed from the image name in the uploads folder and the database everything worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. As there can be several issues going on, none of the shared ones applied to me.

I had thousands of images attached to thousands of posts and none of the migration/import/export tools worked for me. So I did a database migration of `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`. I dumped the files, changed the domain links, etc and uploaded to the new database. But images got the grey tiles, the permalinks were working.

What was going on is that in `wp_postmeta` the `meta_id` like `_wp_attached_file` and `_wp_attachment_metadata` had incorrect names. After I recovered this and reuploaded the `wp_postmeta` datbase it was all good. (perhaps regenerating all images just to be sure is always a good idea).

So check also the database closely.